# Problema recycler view no aparece

Tags: recyclerview

Añadi al Gradle y sincronice sin problemas la librería para el recycervier pero aun así no me muestra los items

Asi me aparece cuando quiero agregar un recyclerview, a la izquierda esta el "recycler view" y a la izquierda un "list view" normal

asi agregue el recyclerview en el xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".gh">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="305dp"
    android:layout_height="452dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
```

[image]

Probe con distintos SDK , pero el recytycle view no me funciona en este proyecto en particular.
Si creo otro nuevo proyecto, en ese nuevo proyecto si me aparecen los items en el recycleview sin problemas, pero en este proyecto que tengo abierto no  puedo.

[image: A la izquierda el recycler view y a la derecha un list view normal]

Comment: Con que código agregas el RecyclerView ?

Comment: enel xml? lo actualice